# How to work google drive push notification api?

Tags: google-sheets, push-notification, google-drive-api, mailchimp

I am trying to do integration between Google sheets and Mailchimp. For this reason, when I add a new row to a sheets then I want to fetch those changes items with google drive push notification API.
I am using this api:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/apiName/apiVersion/resourcePath/watch https://mydomain dot com/notifications(dot replace with .)
```

then i got this type of response:

> X-Goog-Channel-ID: 8bd90be9-3a58-3122-ab43-9823188a5b43
> X-Goog-Channel-Token: 245t1234tt83trrt333
> X-Goog-Channel-Expiration: Tue, 19 Nov 2013 01:13:52 GMT
> X-Goog-Resource-ID:  ret987df98743md8g
> X-Goog-Resource-URI: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes
> X-Goog-Resource-State:  changed
> X-Goog-Message-Number: 23

> {
> "kind": "drive#changes"
> }

Here, we see that we got only resources id which i changed but not the data which i expect.
How can i do now?

Comment: have you read though https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push?

Comment: As mentioned on the documentation posted on the previous comment, the response seems to be correct, what is the issue with it?